# Failed to import extension kiln.py

Tags: kiln

Upgraded to Mercurial 4.7 and now I get "*** failed to import extension kiln from <....>: 'module' object has no attribute 'command'"
I have to enter id/password manually. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're using Kiln Extensions and there are some changes in Mercurial 4.7 that break this.

In regards to the error you referenced, the Mercurial release notes indicate (Section 7, API Changes):

> cmdutil: drop deprecated precursor of registrar.command

So you can resolve this specific issue by replacing `cmdutil.command` with `registrar.command` but that'll just expose other problems.

Personally, I didn't have any more time to mess around with this so I just downgraded to Mercurial 4.6.1.